# How do loop over curl and 'put' different values in API call?

Tags: json, bash, api, curl, circleci

**Objective:** How to loop through over curl statement and 'put' key and value into curl put statement

**Input**: This is my sql query output in json format. for example I mentioned two columns here

```
[{'brand_id': 1, 'brand_name': 'Electra'}]
```

My Curl statement: So what I require is to pass above columnname and value into below curl statement in loop

```
   curl --request PUT \
    --url https://circleci.com/api/v2/context/${contextid}/environment-variable/brand_id\
    --header "Circle-Token: $CIRCLE_TOKEN" \
    --header 'content-type: application/json' \
    --data '{"value":"1"}'
```

next curl should have `brand_name` and `Electra` as substitution to this put

Trying to achieve in this bash

Any suggestion please

Comment: Get items in list by index with `jq` as `echo "[{'brand_id': 1, 'brand_name': 'Electra'}]" | tr "'" '"' | jq -r '.[0]'` and pass to `--data`

Answer (score 0):

suggesting to use `bash` variables and proper `"` quoting.

also suggesting to use `set -x` `set +x` to trace the sent command.

```
brand_id_val=1
brand_name_val="Electra"

set -x
curl --request PUT \
    --url https://circleci.com/api/v2/context/${contextid}/environment-variable/brand_id\
    --header "Circle-Token: $CIRCLE_TOKEN" \
    --header 'content-type: application/json' \
    --data "{\"brand_id\": ${brand_id_val}, \"brand_name\": \"${brand_name_val}\"}"
set +x
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. actually I need to loop through that input file, where i have different column and values.` [{'brand_id': 1, 'brand_name': 'Electra'}]`. This is example like brand_id is column1 and 1 is this value and brand_name is column2 and Electra is its value and so on, I have few other columns as well in input json file, I need to automate process to take 1st column and its value then second column and its value like that in loop to api